# Call A Controller Method in JavaScript to Load View - CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a hidden div that holds a register page. On click of a button the `showSection()` function is called which then slides down the include. Although, I need to pass in some information to that view, and therefore wanted this to be called from my controller.

Heres what I have, I keep getting errors that it does not exist.

controller (called Product_coupon)

```
  public function register($para2=''){
      $page_data['test'] = 'tesssssst';
      $this->load->view('front/myaccount/product_coupon/register', $page_data);
    }
```

File in which the view is supposed to be called.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md center showSection">Create Coupon</button>

<div id="register" style="display:none;"> 

     </div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.showSection').click(function() {
        showRegister();
  });


  function showRegister() {
      var alerta2 = $('#register');
     alerta2.load('<?php echo base_url();?>/myaccount/product_coupon/register');
      $('#register').slideDown(1000);
      $('#hideCreate').fadeIn(90);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass on the content of a view file in codeigniter but not to load as a view, third parameter is needed,

```
public function register($para2='')
{
    $page_data['test'] = 'tesssssst';
    $html = $this->load->view('front/myaccount/product_coupon/register', $page_data,true);
    return $html;
}
```

Notice **true** as a third argument in view function.